# color a csv table

Tags: tables, color, csv, csvsimple, tabularray

I have a CSV file and I want some entries be colored and bold. for example "bezahlt" should be green and bold. "unbezahlt" should be red and bold. "offen" should be black and bold. "unklar" should be stealblue and bold.

the content of the csv file

```
Na,Ku,Re,Be,Da,St
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,240mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{csvsimple}



\begin{document}
    \section*{Be}
    
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|l|c|r|c|c|,
    table head=\hline & Na & Ku& Re & Be& Da & St\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
    {Jan2022.csv}{Na=\Na,Ku=\Ku,Re=\Re,Be=\Be,Da=\Da,St=\St}%
    {\thecsvrow & \Na&\Ku&\Re&\Be&\Da&\St}%
    
    

    
\end{document}
```

I dont know how to add an image to show you the output. But I hope it is clear what I want to achieve.

Thank you for your help

---

Picture of it looks like now

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution with [`csvsimple-l3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) and [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) packages:

---

### For Short Tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
 Na,Ku,Re,Be,Da,St
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\csvreader[
  tabularray = {
    colspec = {|l|l|l|c|r|c|c|},
    cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},   
  },
  table head = \hline & Na & Ku& Re & Be& Da & St\\\hline,
  late after line = \\\hline
]{\jobname.csv}{Na=\Na,Ku=\Ku,Re=\Re,Be=\Be,Da=\Da,St=\St}{
  \thecsvrow & \Na & \Ku & \Re & \Be & \Da &
  \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{offen}{\SetCell{fg=gray3}\St}{
    \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{bezahlt}{\SetCell{fg=green3}\St}{
      \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unbezahlt}{\SetCell{fg=red3}\St}{
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unklar}{\SetCell{fg=azure3}\St}{\St}  
      }
    }    
  }
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### For Long Tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[b6paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
 Na,Ku,Re,Be,Da,St
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
 Bl,Bs,631,238.00,15.01.2022,offen
 Br,Bg,632,309.40,15.01.2022,bezahlt
 Co,Cn,633,309.40,15.01.2022,unbezahlt
 Dr,De,634,952.00,15.01.2022,unklar
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}

\csvreader[
  generic collected table = longtblr,
  generic table options = {[
    %caption = {My Table Caption},
    %label = {my:label},
    label = none,
  ]{
    rowhead = 1,
    colspec = {|l|l|l|c|r|c|c|},
    cell{2-Z}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},   
  }},
  table head = \hline & Na & Ku& Re & Be& Da & St\\\hline,
  late after line = \\\hline
]{\jobname.csv}{Na=\Na,Ku=\Ku,Re=\Re,Be=\Be,Da=\Da,St=\St}{
  \thecsvrow & \Na & \Ku & \Re & \Be & \Da &
  \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{offen}{\SetCell{fg=gray3}}{
    \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{bezahlt}{\SetCell{fg=green3}}{
      \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unbezahlt}{\SetCell{fg=red3}}{
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\St}{unklar}{\SetCell{fg=azure3}}{}  
      }
    }    
  }
  \St
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But this table is just an example. The real table Gas Maybe 100 Lines and this Four words will repeat it‘s Self multiple time. So is the was to fix it. So always when „bezahlt“ Mentioned it becomes green. 
Secondly I like the Idea That the cell geht colored, nice idea, but I meant That just the Word get colored.

Comment: @IHPro I haved updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. I try it out but I don't work yet. I figure out that there is ninecolors package was missing. I fix it, but until yet there is a problem. I try to figure out what is the problem, but the only thing I can read there is "Undefined control sequence. }". Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: I put a picture how it looks like now

Comment: @IHPro You also need to update `csvsimple` package.

Comment: @IHPro Sorry, I am not able to view pictures on this website due to network restrictions.

Comment: I am sorry for this question, but how to update? do you mean add \usepackage{csvsimple} to the Latex file. I took all *.sty from here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple. Latest version. Am I now have to search the old *.sty and remove them ?

Comment: @IHPro It is `\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}`, not `\usepackage{csvsimple}`.

Comment: @IHPro You don't need to download packages from CTAN; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: GreatJob, Thank you very much, I learned I lot

Comment: a little question, If you know. This table can become very large, so since 40 rows I get a trouble. Actually I would use here longtable. But here we use tabularray. Is a way to use tabularray and If the table become to large it put the rest of the rows on the nest page ?

Comment: @IHPro I have added an example for long tables.

Comment: man you are sick, you find always a solution. Is there a way to remove the caption like "Table 1: My Table Caption" or "continued on next page" or write it in german. I have to show it my boss and he can not read english at all.

Comment: @IHPro Edited my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much